# Substituting characters with other characters

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

I want the decipher a certain text. When I encounter a letter in the string, I want to substitute it with the next letter in the alphabet. Then in the next round I want a substitution with the second next letter.

a -> b

k -> l

Then in the second round it should try

a -> c

k -> m

The problem with characters is that it includes all kinds of strange characters, and when you encounter a z and try to substitute it, it  gets substituted with a strange symbol.

Anyone who can help me make some sort of circular list from A-Z? In the following snippet I create a list which contains a to z. In the loop a character is picked, it's index is searched and 'adjusted' and the new character should be retreived. But it doesn't work. (one reason the list being not circular)

```
public static void decipher(){
    String cyphertext = "aVaqrprzoreoeratraWhyvhfraJnygreUbyynaqreqrgjrroebrefinaRqvguZnetbganneNzfgreqnzNaarjvytenntzrrxbzraznnezbrgabtrrarragvwqwrovwbznoyvwiraBznmnyurgzbrvyvwxuroorabzNaarabtrracnnejrxraqnnegrubhqrafpuevwsgRqvguSenaxvarraoevrsnnaTregehqAnhznaauhaiebrtrerohhezrvfwrvaSenaxshegnzZnva";
    char[] plaintext = new char[cyphertext.length()];

    List<Character> a2z = new ArrayList<Character>(26);
    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++){
        a2z.add(Character.valueOf(c));
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < 26; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cyphertext.length(); j++){
            char currentChar = cyphertext.charAt(j);
            int newCharIndex = a2z.indexOf(currentChar)+i;
            plaintext[j] = a2z.get(newCharIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a circular list to handle the edge cases. Further, you should keep in mind that characters `A-Z` have ascii values between 65-90 and `a-z` between 97-122. You *could* create two circular lists, but they're not needed because the edge-cases are easy to handle:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cyphertext = "aVaqrprzoreoeratraWhyvhfraJnygreUbyynaqreqrgjrroebrefinaRqvguZnetbganneNzfgreqnzNaarjvytenntzrrxbzraznnezbrgabtrrarragvwqwrovwbznoyvwiraBznmnyurgzbrvyvwxuroorabzNaarabtrracnnejrxraqnnegrubhqrafpuevwsgRqvguSenaxvarraoevrsnnaTregehqAnhznaauhaiebrtrerohhezrvfwrvaSenaxshegnzZnva";
    char[] plaintext = new char[cyphertext.length()];

    // first shift
    shiftLetters(cyphertext, plaintext, 1);
    // update cyphertext with the intermediate result
    cyphertext = new String(plaintext);
    // second shift
    shiftLetters(cyphertext, plaintext, 2);
    // print result
    System.out.println(new String(plaintext));

}

private static void shiftLetters(String cyphertext, char[] plaintext, int shifts) {
    for (int i=0; i<cyphertext.length(); i++){
        int tmp = cyphertext.charAt(i) + shifts;
        tmp = handleEdgeCases(tmp);
        plaintext[i] = (char)(tmp);
    }
}

// here we handle the "circular" cases
private static int handleEdgeCases(int tmp) {
    if (tmp > 90 && tmp < 97) {
        tmp = tmp - 90 + 65;
    } else if (tmp > 122) {
        tmp = tmp - 122 + 97;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: But what if you shift capital V 12 times, than it's value gets shifted from 86 to 98, and then the program thinks it is a lower case b.

Comment: One small addition, I think -90+65 which results in -25 should be -26. Otherwise: a 'z' with ascii value 122, shifted with 1, becomes 123. Then in the edge method subtract 25 results in 98, which is 'b'. But it needs to be an 'a'.

Comment: @Nils according to the question requirements this code handles only shifts of 1/2. If you want it to support bigger shifts it's an easy change: split `handleEdgeCases()` into two methods, one for lowercase-letters and one for uppercase. This change will solve the issues you described in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
int newCharIndex = a2z.indexOf(currentChar)+i;
plaintext[j] = a2z.get(newCharIndex);
```

The decoded character here is between 0 and 25. Ascii's A-Z goes from 65 to 90. You want to move the index in `a2z` to the range from A to Z:

```
plaintext[j] = a2z.get(newCharIndex) + 'A';
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case, because indexOf(A) should return 0, then +i makes it for examples 1, then get(1) should return a B as a new character, which it does. The problem is when v gets shifted beyond z.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want the substitution cipher to shift letters up by N, wrapping from `Z` to `A`, doing both upper- and lower-case letters, and leave all other characters unchanged.

E.g. if N is 2:

```
a → c  b → d  ...  x → z  y → a  z → b
A → C  B → D  ...  X → Z  Y → A  Z → B
```

Like this?

```
char[] text = "aVaqrprzoreoeratraWhyvhfraJnygreUbyynaqreqrgjrroebrefinaRqvguZnetbganneNzfgreqnzNaarjvytenntzrrxbzraznnezbrgabtrrarragvwqwrovwbznoyvwiraBznmnyurgzbrvyvwxuroorabzNaarabtrracnnejrxraqnnegrubhqrafpuevwsgRqvguSenaxvarraoevrsnnaTregehqAnhznaauhaiebrtrerohhezrvfwrvaSenaxshegnzZnva".toCharArray();
for (int n = 1; n < 26; n++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        char c = text[i];
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            text[i] = (char)('A' + (c - 'A' + n) % 26);
        else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            text[i] = (char)('a' + (c - 'a' + n) % 26);
    }
}
System.out.println(new String(text));
```

*Output*

```
nIndecemberbrengenJuliusenWalterHollanderdetweebroersvanEdithMargotnaarAmsterdamAnnewilgraagmeekomenmaarmoetnogeeneentijdjebijomablijvenOmazalhetmoeilijkhebbenomAnnenogeenpaarwekendaartehoudenschrijftEdithFrankineenbriefaanGertrudNaumannhunvroegerebuurmeisjeinFrankfurtamMain
```

---

Of course, you do realize that shifting by 1, then by 2, then by 3, ... and finally by 26, is the same as shifting once by (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 26), which is 351, and `351 % 26 = 13`.

And a shift by 13 means that encoding and decoding is the same operation.

---

**Explanation**

If you shift by 26, you're shifting exactly a full round, i.e. `a → a  b → b  ...`, so that's the same as not shifting, hence any shift of N >= 26 is the same as N % 26, e.g. `N = 28` is the same as `N = 2`.

A shift by 1 `a → b` then by 2 `b → d` then by 3 `d → g`, is the same as a shift by 1+2+3=6 `a → g`. So a shift by 1+2+...+26=351 is the same as a shift by 351 % 26 = 13.

If variable `c` is an uppercase letter (A-Z), then `c - 'A'` is a number between 0 and 25. Adding an example shift of 6, you get a number 6-31. Doing remainder by 26 (`% 26`) gives you 6-25,0-5 and then `+ 'A'` gives you `G-Z,A-F`, meaning `A → G  B → H  ...  Y → E  Z → F`, each letter shifted by 6.

Same for lowercase letters.

Comment: I figured I would want to shift by 1, then by 2, etc, to print all the intermediate results. So to check what result actually delivered a sensible output. I don't really see why the sum of shifts (351) mod 26 equals to the used amount of shifts.

Comment: I also don't really get the part within the if else if statement.